# ggResidpanel: Add subtitle or title to `resid_panel` graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add a `title` or `subtitle` to my `resid_panel` graph to show MSE. The following code runs error-free but I didn't get what I want.

```
library(emmeans); library(ggResidpanel)
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

resid_panel(warp.lm) + labs(subtitle = "MSE = 5745")
```

using `ggtitle` instead of `labs` didn't work, either.

The red mark that reads "MSE = 5745" is where I want my title to be. Thanks a lot in advance.
[image]